# Trouble Dropping Unique Constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PG:

I made a user table that includes unique emails, but later decided that emails should not be unique. I pushed changes to make my email field non-unique (I use an ORM, so I don't actually have the exact SQL that took place), but PG still won't let me use duplicate email addresses.

I checked the index and it's not unique, but there's a constraint keeping me from having duplicate email addresses. However I'm having trouble dropping this constraint. What am I doing wrong?

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE "users" DROP CONSTRAINT "unique_users_email"
PGError: ERROR:  constraint "unique_users_email" of relation "users" does not exist

SQL> UPDATE users SET email = 'test@test.com'
PGError: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_users_email"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=(test@test.com) already exists.
```

Comment: perhaps there is a place to commit changes?

Also, try:

`ALTER TABLE "users"
disable CONSTRAINT "unique_users_email";`

Comment: @jt234 That didn't work.`PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CONSTRAINT"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "users" disable CONSTRAINT "unique_users_email";` My changes seem to be committing just fine, except for this problem.

Comment: how about DISABLE TRIGGER ALL?

Comment: Here is pretty much everything you can do with a table: [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-altertable.html)

Comment: @jt234 You can't `DISABLE` a `CONSTRAINT` in Pg.

Comment: @AlexQueue Please show the output of "\d+ users" in `psql`; it's hard to help you when working blind. It certainly sounds like you're in an odd situation. Exactly *what* ORM are you using? And what PostgreSQL version?

Comment: Sounds like you've still got a unique index.  \d on the table, as Craig suggests, should show if you do.

Comment: I ended up resetting the DB (I was still in test so it wasn't an issue). As such I can no longer reproduce this.

Answer (score 5):

I bet that "unique_users_email" is actually the name of a unique **index** rather than a constraint. Try:

`DROP INDEX "unique_users_email";`

Recent versions of psql should tell you the difference between a unique index and a unique constraint when looking at the `\d` description of a table.

Comment: Be sure to specify the schema if the table is not part of the public schema: DROP INDEX myschema.unique_users_email;