# How do I reverse a Postgresql unique index constraint in a rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

I created a unique index on my model like so:

`add_index(:courses, :name, unique: true)`

I no longer require the name to be unique. I think I have the same problem as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922500/trouble-dropping-unique-constraint), so I worked through those suggestions to no avail.

I receive errors like "ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_courses_on_name" when I try to add a record with the same name.

To remove the unique constraint I've tried:

1. `remove_index :courses, :name`

   (migration succeeds, but later I get the same error suggesting there is still a uniqueness constraint)
2. `execute "ALTER TABLE courses DROP CONSTRAINT unique_index_courses_on_name"`
3. `execute "ALTER TABLE courses DROP CONSTRAINT index_courses_on_name"`
4. `execute "ALTER TABLE courses DROP CONSTRAINT unique_name"`
5. `execute "ALTER TABLE courses DROP CONSTRAINT name"`
6. `execute "ALTER TABLE courses DROP INDEX index_courses_on_name"`
7. `execute "ALTER TABLE courses DROP INDEX courses_on_name"`
8. `execute "DROP INDEX unique_courses_name"`

(PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  index "unique_courses_name" does not exist)

9. `execute "ALTER TABLE courses disable CONSTRAINT unique_courses_name"`

(PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CONSTRAINT"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE courses disable CONSTRAINT unique_courses_name)

10. `execute "ALTER TABLE courses DROP INDEX unique_courses_name"`

I'm on psql 9.4.4, Rails 4.2, and my last ounce of sanity. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Show the table definition from `psql`, e.g. `\dt courses`

Comment: @craig - it says no relations found in dev and can't find the db connection in production (I presume because it's a URL to the db rather than in /var on Heroku). I'm going to investigate why I'm getting this error despite it seeming to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think unique will be removed if you remove the old index and add it again

```
class RemoveUniqueFromCoursesName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_index(:courses, :name)
    add_index(:courses, :name)
  end
end
```

Comment: I agree this _should_ work, and like in my attempt #1 above the migration runs but the db constraint remains, preventing me from adding a record with a duplicate name. I think the error is deeper in my config and this is just the symptom.